# Magento 2.2.3 - Get all categories in store programmatically

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.2, object-manager, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to gather all categories in my store.

As a start I'm using the object manager.

I know it is bad practise to use the objectmanager directly, but after this I will convert it into a block class with dependency injection.

This is the code in my view to gather the categories:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categories = $categoryFactory->getStoreCategories(false,false,true);
```

When I dump `$objectManager, categoryFactory or $categories` in my view, the memory of my development server will fill up. After the server reaches the memory limit my browser will give this as a response `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Comment: http://www.matheusgontijo.com/2018/02/10/magento-2-working-with-large-collections-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-xxxx-bytes-exhausted/?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_feed%3BLNL954zRRzeAkMh775S%2F3g%3D%3D

Comment: @BilalUsean Thanks for the link, but my Magento store is a fresh install with 4 categories and 2 products... Can this problem occur with this 'small' setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected $_storeManager;
protected $_categoryCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

public function getCategories(){
     $categories = $this->_categoryCollection->create()                              
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched

     foreach ($categories as $category){
         $category->getName();
     }
 }
```

call `$block->getCategories()` function from your phtml file.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this. The first part with the constructor needs to be placed in a block class, and the rest of the code in the view?

Comment: answer updated ... now you can call function in phtml file

Comment: Thank you Ronak, this makes sense. I tried to inject `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory` in the constructor, so I can use it as a variable. But it gives me `Undefined class CollectionFactory`. In the answer @Nikhil Vaghela gave he uses another class.. I'm getting a bit confused coding in Magetno I'm sorry...

Comment: remove generation folder from var and then try again or run command :
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 1):

Please try it

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

 $storeManager = $objectManager->Create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository');    


    $categories = $objectManager->Create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection')
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc');

        $categories->setStore($storeManager->getStore()); 

    foreach($categories as $category){

        echo $category->getId().'--'.$category->getName();
        echo '<br>';

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a reference where I can see all the options? Like `$category->getId()` and `$category->getName()`? Cause my editor says Method not found

Comment: @FrankGroot you can see all options by `$category->getData()` this code